# Why hintEnd not render in formly with material?

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I try to use the `hintEnd` from [material with formly option](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/main/src/ui/material/form-field/src/form-field.wrapper.ts#L80):

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="to.hintEnd as hintEnd" align="end">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="stringOrTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ content: hintEnd }">
    </ng-container>
</mat-hint>
```

In the form structure like this:

```
{
    key: "text",
    type: "input",
    templateOptions: {
      label: "type something here...",
      placeholder: "Placeholder",
      description: "Description",
      hintEnd: "this is the hint at the end!" // <----- here.
    }
 }
```

But in the ui the text is not appear and I got no error.

Why? what I missing here?

[The example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-clarke-qt1rx?file=/src/app/form.component.ts:648-909)